# Dynamic initialisation of form in Django

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to initialise a form dynamically. This is my forms.py:

```
class MapLocalityForm(forms.Form):


def search_locs(self, location):
    print("inside form")
    print(location)
    return Locality.objects.filter(name=location)

def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    self.loc = kwargs.pop('loc', None)
    super(MapLocalityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['locality'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset='',widget=forms.RadioSelect(),required=True,
                                      initial=1)
    if self.loc:
        loc_term = self.loc
        # print(loc_term)
        loc_list = self.search_locs(loc_term)
        # print(loc_list)
        self.fields['locality'].queryset = loc_list
    else:
        self.fields['locality'].queryset = Locality.objects.none()
```

So I perform a check in views.py:

```
def map_locality(request,freq_term):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = MapLocalityForm(request.POST, loc=freq_term)
        if form.is_valid():
            "do something"
    else:
        form = MapLocalityForm()
return render(request, 'maplocalities.html', {'form': form,'loc':freq_term,'alias_created':alias_created})
```

I am directed to this view using a redirect option, so the request is GET. Whenever I jump to this maplocalities.html, I get an empty form because the code goes to the else part and there are no arguments. Usually when we create a form which is static, a form is displayed when it goes to the else part. Any idea ow can I rectify my view to perform just like static forms.

Comment: What do you mean with static form? Cause the else part is supposed to show you a new Form to be filled.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question either. Are you trying to pre-fill a form using arguments from a GET rather than a POST request?

Comment: @IrisG. When I say static form I mean the form values are not dependent on another value as input.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: I am trying to create this form using the value of freq_term which is only available when I hit the maplocalities url.

Comment: Well as you said yourself, it's a GET request. Your code for that only recognizes POST requests. You can do the same thing with GET as you're doing with POST if you just adjust your code slightly.

Comment: I did try that as well. I replaced request.POST with request.GET but then everytime I hit the url I get a field error that "This field is required", this error should have come when I would have placed an empty form submission in maplocalities page.